# REST interface and leading zeroes

Tags: mongodb, rest

I'm using Mongo's simple REST interface to query data in my collection.

One field I'm searching on is a mixture of numeric and character data, e.g. 000107011JXK

If I do the following query:

```
http://[server]:[port]/[db]/[collection]/?filter_[field]=000107011JXK
```

... Mongo removes leading zeroes and only searches on the numerical part of the criteria (e.g. 107011) which obviously does not bring back the required results.

Is there any way I can get around this issue?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: How about this "000107011JKX" ??

Comment: Afraid not! If I do so then it explicitly looks for quotes within the data, which it doesn't have.